# How can I redirect ip in apache2

Tags: apache, url, redirect, ip, apache2

I have problem. I want for redirect my url when I type in browser 'mysite.dev' to  'www.mysite.dev.com'. I tried this:

```
<If "req('Host') != 'www.example.com'">
```

RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.example.com$1

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: First it doesn't look like apache configuration syntax. But I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want everything to be send to www.mysite.dev.com ?